# Disabling swipe left and right event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am gonna disable swipe event (exactly right and left on slider part) on website mobile view.
This is my js code.

```
jQuery(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", '#sample_slider', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This doesn't work on #sample_slider element.

Or did point wrong element for swipe?

Comment: On click, toggle a state (in `data`, let's call it `carSelected`) and on your div, make a `v-if` to check if `carSelected` is true, then it comes down to html + css for the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Use :hover css property and pass `pointer-events:none;` style to the element this should do the trick
In your `someAction()` function you will need to perform this

However, as a dev to dev using the @click event like this is the dumbest way to use Vue.. but considering that there might be a need in your app for this i think my solution should help you

Comment: Not sure why it's dumb. Your click can mutate a state and it's still Vue's job to handle reactivity and allow for dynamic CSS to be applied to an element.

Comment: Well What kind of actions are you going to perform with `@click` on a input element which is already nested under a div with its own `@click` event..

Comment: Not sure why a child and a parent cannot have 2 separate actions tbh. They **can** totally be unrelated depending of the UI. Ofc, you'll need to prevent the propagation, but it's not really related to Vue handling reactivity here.

Comment: excatly my point if it is a child put it into a different component and listen for a action on the div and have a `@click`, but putting them in one file and both having `@click` is not a wise way it will cause conflits.. and that is why i did say "Considering that there might be a need in your app"

Comment: You don't need to have them separated on various files. You can totally get 20 `@click` in the same `.vue` file. Splitting a single component into several should not be a rule of thumb in any way. It should be logic on it's functionality more than just on "oh damn, there is another click, I need to kick it into another file". There will be as much _conflicts_ if it's put into another file too tbh. Still, it's totally fine to have a parent click listener and a child click listener if it does make sense in OP's context.